# Applet tag fallback / alternate content

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, firefox, applet

In Chrome and Firefox if the Java plugin is disabled it simply displays the "plugin disabled" box in place of the applet.  However, I need it to display the alternate content instead.

```
<applet code="com.example.Applet.class" id="applet" mayscript
    codebase="/public/applets" archive="applet.jar" width="530" height="330">
    <param name="scriptable" value="true"/>
    <param name="progressbar" value="true"/>
    Alternate content here
</applet>
```

Is there any way to get this content to show?  JavaScript is an acceptable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can include Java's [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#appletTagAttributes) with

```
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
```

then `deployJava.isPluginInstalled()` should return true/false depending on whether the plugin is installed. Based on the answer, replace the `<applet>` with the *alternate content* using JS DOM manipulation.

Depending on how the *alternate content* is marked up you could use any of the usual suspects ([`.textContent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent), `.getElementById()`, `.getElementsByClassName()` etc…) to do the replacement.

In my limited testing, `deployJava.isPluginInstalled()` returns *false* in Chrome after disabling the plugin via `chrome://plugins` and *true* in Firefox with the plugin running. I tested this on the [Applet Test Page](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) after pasting the contents of `deployJava.js` in the Console.

Comment: Using `isPluginInstalled` did not work, but `deployJava.versionCheck("1.6.0+")` does